# Screenshot visual comparison only for the element, not the entire page

Tags: typescript, playwright, playwright-test

Chromium does not create full page screenshots, the icons from my footer are missing. Webkit and Firefox don't have this problem. Therefore, I want to focus the test on comparing screenshots of certain elements.

I understand how to take a screenshot of the entire page and make a visual comparison. But it is not clear how exactly to do the same, but only for the selected elements.

I tried to solve the problem with rendering the whole page, but all the variations did not give a stable result. I have tried these ways:

- scroll page down > scroll back up
- scroll down pages > scroll back (repeatedly)
- scroll to bottom of page > wait (up to 30 seconds) > scroll back (repeatedly)
  etc.

And here is my question:

1. How to take screenshots of only a specific element and compare, not the whole page
2. How can I set a complex name in the format I need (example in the code)

The first lines of code may seem confusing, but this is due to the fact that one test will run in 70 geolocations.

```js
//@ts-check
import { test, expect } from '@playwright/test';
import { skipMobile } from '../helpers/device-helpers';
import { geolocations } from '../data/geo-massive';

geolocations.forEach(g=>
test.describe(
`${g.name} - Checking the opening of the site loading Web, taking into account the array of geolocations`, () => {
test('test', async ({ browser, browserName, isMobile  }) => {

//skip mobile browser
skipMobile(browserName, isMobile);

//Settings the test
const context = await browser.newContext({
  permissions: ['geolocation'],
  ignoreHTTPSErrors: true,
  proxy: {
    server: g.server,
    username: g.username,
    password: g.password
    },
    locale: g.localebrowser,
  })
const page = await context.newPage();
    await page.setViewportSize({ width: 1440, height: 900 });
    await page.goto('https://stackoverflow.com/');
    await page.waitForSelector('.s-topbar--searchbar--input-group');

**// I'm taking a screenshot of an element, but I need to give it a complex name,
// similar to the second screenshot command.**
    await expect(page).toHaveScreenshot({ path: browserName + ` ${g.name} checkPayMethod.png`});

    await expect(page.locator('.footer-position__logo-container')).toHaveScreenshot(` ${g.name} checkPayMethod.png`);
    
    
    await context.close();
    await browser.close();
  });
}))
```

Answer (score 0):

I found that the playwright's documentation was not very clear, but to take a screenshot of just the element, is as simple as defining the element.

```
    await expect(page.locator('#showData')).toHaveScreenshot({ maxDiffPixels: 100 });
```

I can see you are first taking a full-page screenshot, and then taking a screenshot of the element, so maybe just try to do one or the other. Probably the test is failing because is not able to pass the full screenshot assertion.

I would recommend you remove the line below from your code

```
    await expect(page).toHaveScreenshot({ path: browserName + ` ${g.name} checkPayMethod.png`});
```